# Resources running on worker node

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I'm new to kubernetes and trying to understand what resources resides on which node.

Can anyone please confirm what kind of kubernetes resources other than pods are usually worker node hosts  ? On which nodes do other resources like ingress, persistence-volume-claim, service, config map etc resides ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Pramode Kumar Pandit,

On Workers you will run your workload, such as deployed microservices,  the ingress run on your master node.
the Persistence volumes will depend how you configure your ICP to determine where it will run.
If you look at this post you will have an idea about the architecture using ICP:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_3.1.2/getting_started/architecture.html